# Statistical outcomes from motivational literature

Tags: reference-request, experimental-psychology, motivation

I am thinking about doing a research about potential harm and benefits of motivational literature from the statistical learning perspective. I hence wonder if there is any existing  research on this topic.

I guess what I have in mind is a study that includes two similar groups of people. The group A will be given some motivational literature to read, whereas another group will not be provided with such literature and controlled to never have an exposure to it. Those groups will then be monitored for several years to make analysis about their average success.

I perfectly understand that such a study is practically impossible, so I was wondering if anything at leasta a bit along those lines was done.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.